# How to create a visual sitemap of a large existing website?

Tags: sitemap

I need to evaluate a current existing website's sitemap and structure. Normally i utilize a patchwork of utilities and programs and end up creating the visual site with either illustrator or slickmaps for a browser based solution. 
I have started down this road again and realize this site is much too large to do this all by hand. My "dream" solution would create an attractive diagram of the website possibly from an xml file, and show cross linking and those kinds of relationships. The icing on the cake would be if i could also get it to mashup with google analytics site visitation metrics - but that would probably be asking too much...
Any help appreciated...
Shawna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need sitemap for seo? We use at http://applehub.us/ huge xml file generated by script. I think it would useless create site map for users

Answer (score 0):

For building flow diagram of a website you can try the [Site Visualizer](http://site-visualizer.com/) software.

Run the app, create new project, enter URL of the site, then click Start button. After the site will be crawled, go to Visual Sitemap tab and click Draw button. Similar visual structure of the website will be drawn:

[image: visual sitemap]

Click on a page in order to highlight all its outbound links. Click on Save button to save the diagram to an image file.

More info is available [here](http://site-visualizer.com/visual-sitemap).

Comment: Is there a build for Linux?